# Android shell use application permissions

Tags: android, linux, shell

Android adb shell has extra permissions compared to ordinary applications. For example, it can access all or most /proc subdirectories. How to run shell with permissions as if it was an ordinary application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a specific shell command for a specific **debuggable** package like this:

`adb shell "run-as com.example.mypackage my_command"`